# setOnItemClickListener doesn't work

Tags: android, listview, listener

I have a listview with an adapter but when I click on the listview I have no response. I have tried with some of the responses of other posts like [setOnItemClickListener Not Working In Custom Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16393718/setonitemclicklistener-not-working-in-custom-listview) or [Android - setOnItemClickListener event of ListView not working in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16834678/android-setonitemclicklistener-event-of-listview-not-working-in-fragment) but I can't resolve the problem. I show you my code.

First, the mainActivity

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {

private MainView view;

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(icicle);

   Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();
   String[] array=b.getStringArray("listaEventos");

   /**A continuación, generamos los distintos valores que ocuparán el LinearLayout, concretamente
    * las categorías de los eventos.
    */

   String[] values = new String[] { "Actividades vacacionales", "Aire libre y excursiones", "Cine",
    "Conferencias y otros", "Congresos y jornadas", "Cursos y talleres", "Deporte", "Escénicas",
    "Exposiciones", "Ferias", "Fiestas y festivales", "Música", "Viajes", "Otras" };

   /**
    * Llamamos al adapter personalizado para mostrar la vista.
    */
   MyListCategoryArrayAdapter adapter = new MyListCategoryArrayAdapter(this, values, array);
   setListAdapter(adapter);

   //Log.d("YA SE HA ADAPTADO", "YA SE HA ADAPTADO");

   view = (MainView)View.inflate(this, R.layout.all_products, null);
   //view.setViewListener(viewListener);
   setContentView(view);
```

}

Then, the adapterActivity:

```
public class MyListCategoryArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Context context;
private final String[] values;
private final String[] listanumber2;

public MyListCategoryArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values, String[]   listanumber) {
super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, values);
this.context = context;
this.values = values;
this.listanumber2 = listanumber;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  if(convertView==null){

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
  }
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
        TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);
        TextView textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.number);

        textView.setText(values[position]);

        String categoria = values[position];

        if (categoria.startsWith("Actividades vacacionales")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_vacaciones);
            textView2.setText(listanumber2[0].trim()+" eventos");
        }
        if (categoria.startsWith("Aire libre y excursiones")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_aire_libre_excursiones);
            textView2.setText(listanumber2[1].trim()+" eventos");
        }
        if (categoria.startsWith("Cine")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_cine);
            textView2.setText(listanumber2[2].trim()+" eventos");
        }
        if (categoria.startsWith("Conferencias y otros")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_conferencias);
            textView2.setText(listanumber2[3].trim()+" eventos");
        }
        if (categoria.startsWith("Congresos y jornadas")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_congresos_jornadas);
            textView2.setText(listanumber2[4].trim()+" eventos");
        }
        if (categoria.startsWith("Cursos y talleres")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_curso_taller);
            textView2.setText(listanumber2[5].trim()+" eventos");
        }
        if (categoria.startsWith("Deporte")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_deporte);
            textView2.setText(listanumber2[6].trim()+" eventos");
        }
        if (categoria.startsWith("Escénicas")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_escenicas);
            textView2.setText(listanumber2[7].trim()+" eventos");
        }
        if (categoria.startsWith("Exposiciones")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_exposiciones);
            textView2.setText(listanumber2[8].trim()+" eventos");
        }
        if (categoria.startsWith("Ferias")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_ferias);
            textView2.setText(listanumber2[9].trim()+" eventos");
        }
        if (categoria.startsWith("Fiestas y festivales")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_fiesta_festival);
            textView2.setText(listanumber2[10].trim()+" eventos");
        }
        if (categoria.startsWith("Música")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_musica);
            textView2.setText(listanumber2[11].trim()+" eventos");
        }
        if (categoria.startsWith("Viajes")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_viajes);
            textView2.setText(listanumber2[12].trim()+" eventos");
        }
        if (categoria.startsWith("Otras")) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.pic_otros);
            textView2.setText(listanumber2[13].trim()+" eventos");
        }
  return convertView;



}
```

Then, the View which I use to caught the user interaction:

```
    /**
 * Find our references to the objects in the xml layout
 */
@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();

    final ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    list.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int position, long arg3) {
            Log.d("HERE IT DOES NOT ENTER", "HERE IT DOES NOT ENTER");
        }
    });


  final Button button0 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button0.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Boton0000", "Boton0000");

        }
    });
  final Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

  button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Boton1111", "Boton1111");

        }
  }); 

    final Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Boton2222", "Boton2222");

        }
    }); 

    final Button button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("Boton3333", "Boton3333");

        }
    }); 
}
```

Finally, I show the .xml for the listView and every row of the list:

all.products.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.agendajovenzgz.view.MainView  
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clickable="false"
>
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="389dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:focusable="true"  />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:text="Mapa" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    android:text="Lista" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    android:text="Buscador" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
    android:text="Más" />
 </com.agendajovenzgz.view.MainView>
```

rowlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:padding="6dip"

 >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:focusable="false" 
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/label"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"      
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Can someone help me please??

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Comment: Try removing the `list.setItemsCanFocus(false)` portioin

Comment: try setting the clicklistener on each convertview inside the method `getView`

Comment: zgz7009 - The behavior is the same. Nothing changes. Olayinka - I have proved with convertView.setClickable(true); and  convertView.setOnClickListener(null); I don't know if you refer this. The result is that I can't click on the listview. Before the change, I can click, I know because the row is selected with other colour. Setting the clicklistener nothing happens when i click.

Comment: try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20208285/listview-itemclick-not-work/20208788#20208788) way.i hope you will get help.

Answer (score 0):

You should override onListItemClick in your extended ListActivity.

Comment: Yes, good eye noticing the extends ListActivity. Extending from Activity is also a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try not use a ListView, necessarily. Name the list view by some name in android:

`android:id="@+id/my_list"`

and then reference that in your MainActivity:

`ListView myList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.my_list);`

You may then set myList to `onItemClickListener` with:

```
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

             // Your code here

    }
});
```

You need not worry about post-inflating, as there will be no items for the user to click on until the ListView is inflated. Without using a ListActivity, you can get rid of `onFinishInflate()` and the call to its parent, and simply put all your click listeners in your `onCreate()` method.

Also, another tip - declare your variables outside the `onCreate()` method and define them at the beginning on the `onCreate()` method. This will make them global across the Activity, so you will not need the `final` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

In `ListActivity`, `onContentChanged` does various things, including setting its own `OnItemClickListener`.

This `OnItemClickListener` calls the `onListItemClick` method in `ListActivity`.

Therefore, to make it work, you need to either

- Use `onListItemClick` instead of setting an `OnItemClickListener`
- **OR** set the `OnItemClickListener` **after** you have called `setContentView` (possibly in `onAttachedToWindow`, which should occur after, but I have not tested this).

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the clickable property to false for your all your textview.

android:clickable="false"

Answer (score 0):

set the `OnItemClickListener` to the `ListView` during `Activity#onCreate()`

```
// inside activity
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // calls to super and setcontentview

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { ......
```

Comment: This works for me but this way i have the listview listener in the main activity and the four buttons listener in the view. My goal is to have all the listeners in the view, for divide the code better

Comment: You should not nest views unless they are containers like `LinearLayout` and so. Yes you can but you shouldn't. Move all the listeners declaration to the `Activity#onCreate()`